# Select the last <a> in a series of classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a unordered list nested inside of an unordered list like below:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Event Overview</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

I need to select the last `<a>` inside of `<ul class="sub-menu">`

I would presume that the selector would be `$(".sub-menu a:last")` but this only selects the absolute last a. I need it to select the last a in every unordered list with a class of sub-menu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('.sub-menu li:last-child a')
```

> Select the `a`
>   contained in the last `li` child of
>   each `.sub-menu` element.

You don't want to select `a:last-child` because every `a` is the last and only child of its `li` element.

Nor do you want to select `a:last` or `li:last` unless you [iterate through it as John Hartsock says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758019/jquery-selectors-select-the-last-a-in-a-series-of-classes/5758044#5758044), because [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector) picks the last element *in an entire jQuery DOM element set*.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul.submenu").each(function () {
   $("a:last", this)  // this will select the last a in each submenu
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('.sub-menu').each(function() {
        $('li:last a', this) // do stuff
    });
});
```

Added a fiddle of how this works: http://jsfiddle.net/mzyx3/